# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am trying to use fullPage in my site. I have two section divs within on "fullPage" div. My error has to do with a script that I'm leaving out, but I can't tell which one.  I think that I'm adding the necessary scripts and in the necessary order, but my my error shows that not to be the case. 
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullpage.js/jquery.fullPage.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fullPage.js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <header> 
       <h1 class = "page-title">Columbia Ride Share</h1>
       <nav>
           <ul>
              \.....
           </ul>
       </nav>
  </header>
  <div id ="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "JFK">
            <h6>JFK</h6>
               <p> <a href = "toJFK.html">to</a>
                   <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "Newark">
           <h6>NEWARK</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "bottomRow">
           <h6>LAGUARDIA</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
           <div class = "createRide">
              <button class = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">CREATE A RIDE</button>
           </div>    
           <div id="id02" class="modal">
           <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
               <div class="imgcontainer">
                       <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                   </div>
           <div class = "loginMsg">
                       <p>Where are you headed?<p>
                           <a href="create-a-ride-to-airport.html">I need a ride to the airport</a>
                           <a href="create-a-ride-from-airport.html">I need a ride to campus</a>
                    </div>
        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div class="section" id="section1"> 
          <div class = "welcome">
               <div class = "intro">
                   <p>Lorem ipsum elementum libero curae nam in id maecenas per, inceptos dui a aliquam velit eu ullamcorper ultricies platea, nibh adipiscing pulvinar nunc justo taciti non magna interdum lectus ligula cursus ornare aenean lacus tincidunt, semper gravida bibendum vitae laoreet morbi pharetra, nunc tellus donec imperdiet cubilia consectetur.Suscipit fermentum euismod etiam facilisis metus quam litora blandit himenaeos, convallis placerat felis mollis aliquam ante fringilla morbi tincidunt, at curabitur ligula sapien iaculis risus nullam platea morbi cursus adipiscing aliquet tempor commodo quis leo metus sem dictum.</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.10/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
</script>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
        jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
    }else{
        jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
</script>
<script> 
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick= function(event){

    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>  
      window.onload = function() {
         initApp();
      };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `.fullPage()`? Alphabetic case is important in JavaScript.

Comment: loading `jquery.fullPage.js` and `fullPage.js/jquery.fullPage.min.js` looks suspect too (but not the problem)

Comment: @Pointy you're right - that was my mistake. Even after changing it, I get the same error.

Comment: Try to use only one jQuery ，replace the 1.11 with the below 3.1.1.

Comment: @ wuxiandiejia ah yes - that got rid of my error thank you!